# Specifying EntityManager in Singleton EJB; access from Stateless EJB. OK? Bad?

Tags: jpa, transactions, jndi, entitymanager

I want to abstract the details of specifying an EntityManager from the majority of the implementation, so I've put the `@PersistenceContext(...) EntityManager em;` declaration in a `@Singleton` bean.  That bean has a `getEm()` method which the rest of the app uses to get the EntityManager (there are actually several EntityManagers, all done this same way). Each `@Stateless` bean that does  JPA-related ops injects the `@Singleton` bean, and then calls the `getEm()` method to get the EntityManager.

There are three primary reasons for this approach: (1) keep the specification of `unitName` in the `@PersistenceContext` declaration in one place (i.e., avoiding repeated injections of `@PersistenceContext` repeating the `unitName`); (2) keep options open to change acquisition of the EntityManager from being injected to JNDI lookup later on; (3) when using multiple entity managers in a live/standby scenario, allow some logic to dynamically determine the proper one.

Few questions:

1. Is this approach inherently flawed?  If so, is there a better way to accomplish the 3 objectives listed?
2. When acquiring the EntityManager in this way (when injected into the `@Singleton`), will each `@Stateless` bean get a "fresh" EntityManager for every transaction (container-managed transactions).  Or do I need to do something specific to prevent the EntityManager the `@Stateless` bean is [re]using from becoming stale?
3. Same as #2 for JNDI lookup in the `@Singleton`.
4. If each transaction isn't getting a "fresh" EntityManager (presumably due to some JPA/JTA interactions), then I suspect this approach isn't thread-safe due to multiple `@Stateless` acquisition of single EntityManager from `@Singleton`. Any approaches to address that?